# Scheduled Tasks - VB6 and Threading

Tags: multithreading, vb6

I manage a group of scheduled tasks that run daily.  The scheduled tasks launch a visual basic 6 application, which calls a function depending on the parameter passed.  For example, if an 'A' was passed to the scheduled task then function 1 is run and if a B is passed to the scheduled task then function 2 is run etc.  However, function 1 and function 2 also call function 3.

My question is about Threading.  As both function 1 and function 2 call function 3, should I have some form of Threading in the application?

Comment: You need to review your previously asked questions and *mark as answer* appropriately before anyone will add another answer to this question

Comment: Agree with Matt. Use the check mark next to the answer to accept an answer to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Those functions are never called simultaneously.

- If "A" is passed, then function 1 is run, and it then calls function 3.
- If "B" is passed, then function 2 is run, and it then calls function 3.

Function 3 is never called twice at the same time.

Comment: Could you explain a simple scenario were threading is required? VB6 is the language I am using.

Comment: Never use threading with VB6 and you'll be much safer. Really. Just don't do it. It doesn't support threading natively.

Comment: What happens if scheduled task A takes 24 hours to run (function 3 called millions of times) and scheduled task B takes 243 hours to run (function 3 called millions of times)?

Comment: To answer your question, nothing special. Scheduled task A takes 24 hours to run, and task B takes 243 hours to run. I get the feeling that you assume that it task A and task B are running at the same time, function 3 can only be run by EITHER task A OR task B.  Since there are two completely separate instances of your executable in memory at the same time, this is not the case.

Comment: What is the best solution for this? function 3 contains an SQL Update statement. I am concerned that there could be concurrency issues if task B runs the update statement before task A has had chance to.

Comment: You don't need to take any action at all. You do not have a problem.

Comment: @John Saunders, I am still confused by this.  Surely if two scheduled tasks are running at the same time (one calling function 1 and one calling function 2), then function 3 could be called at the same time?

Comment: Is there something being referenced by function 3 that makes running it in multiple processes an issue?  If you are connecting to a database, there are various mechanisms within SQL Server to maintain data integrity.  You may have to find a way to gracefully handle the cases where an update fails if the command can't execute due to a table being locked preventing the update.

Comment: @w0051977: no. The two functions are running as part of two different instances of a class and are running in different processes. Totally isolated.

Comment: @John Saunders, thanks.  The scenario I was concerned about was: function 1 comes in and runs part of function 2 before passing control back.  Function 2 then runs function 3 and does a partial update before passing control back.  When function 2 takes control again it will be operating on different data (based on the update complete for function 1).

Comment: @w0051977: that's what transactions are for.

Comment: @John Saunders, that was the answer I was looking for.  The function in question only has one update but I am planning to add another within a Transaction.  Unfortunately I have already upvoted the answer.  +1 for comment.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is No, because VB6 does not allowing the creation of threads.  But even if you were using a language with threading support, it is not clear why a common shared subroutine (function) would need to be called with a seperate thread.

Comment: There is an SQL update statement in function 3.  The scenario I am concerned about is this: 
1) Function 1 calls function 3. 
2) Before function 3 completes (step 1),function 2 calls function 3 and runs an SQL update
3) Function 3 finishes (step 1) and calls an SQL update

I believe I should get an error in this scenario because the cursor will recognise that the data has changed.  I am new to threading.

Comment: We need more information about what steps 1 and 2 do before we can determine how step 3 will be affected - with respect to any SQL being run.

Comment: This is really a database / SQL issue.  I actually suggest starting a new question with the details of the SQL operations you are running concurrently so you can get the audience, and the answers, you are looking for.  It is not VB6-specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing implicit to VB that means you need to use multiple threads or be mindful of it.
Multiple process are already completely separate.

If that function itself is doing something with shared data (on disk, database, registry, etc) then you may need some sort of locking. What you need depends on what it's doing though.